# how can I model db for filterable data

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I'm build a new application for universities.

I need to show news about dynamic categories has dynamic sub-categories each university or all universities.

for example:

```
universities:
-Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1A
    name: Harvard
-Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1B
    name: Cambridge

categories:
-Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1C
    name: Faculties
-Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1E
    name: Work

subcategories:
-Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1F
    name: Engineering Faculty
    category: -Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1C
-Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1H
    name: Full Time
    category: -Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1E
-Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1G
    name: Part Time
    category: -Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1E

news:
-Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1I
    name: Deliver Man
    content: "lorem ipsum..."
    category: -Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1E
-Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1J
    name: Teacher announcement
    content: "lorem ipsum..."
    category: -Lo7NftMRUrF73Bq9A1C
```

This model doesn't use universities table. All users can see all content.

I want to change this model for below usage.

All users can see all universities contents AND All users can see only selected a university contents thanks to filtering system.

Also each university should has specific categories and subcategories system.

For Example: Harvard has Work category but Cambridge has not Work category.

I don't know is it possible?